# CUPTI / CUDA prof_trigger not working as expected

Tags: cuda, profiling

According to NVidia, __prof_trigger() calls are executed at warp-level, or in other words, each warp will increment the specified trigger by 1.

So i wrote a small kernel to test this out:

```
__global__ void kernel(int *arr) {
   __prof_trigger(00);

   // from here, it's irrevelant to the question
   int id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
   if (id >= N) return;
   __prof_trigger(01);
   if (arr[id] < 4) __prof_trigger(02);
   else             __prof_trigger(03);
}
```

I invoke the program using:
    ./prof_trigger_test [block_size] [event_name]

The input array is irrelevant at this point (i'm just testing prof_trigger_0, so it doesn't even get to be used)

i only tested with a single block (from my understanding, different amount of blocks shouldn't affect this question, or am i wrong?) and event name is the name given by CUPTI, or prof_trigger_XX, which is translated to the event id in runtime.

So given that warp size is 32, i should expect something like:

```
./prof_trigger_test 1  prof_trigger_00   // expected to return 1
./prof_trigger_test 33 prof_trigger_00   // expected to return 2
```

prof_trigger_00 should increase each time i increase the number of threads by 32 (which requires a new warp)

This is not the case. When running on my latop, with a NVidia 9600M GT, instead of 32, i only need to increase by 4 to see an incremented value of the counter. And running on a remote cluster, using a Tesla M2070, the required increment is 8

So clearly i'm missing something. Is the GPU creating smaller warps for some reason (performance, i would think, although not sure how)?

Here is the entire code, as requested:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cupti.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

#define CHECK_CU_ERROR(err, cufunc)                                     \
    if (err != CUDA_SUCCESS) {                                          \
        printf("%s:%d: error %d for CUDA Driver API function '%s'\n",   \
                __FILE__, __LINE__, err, cufunc);                       \
        exit(-1);                                                       \
    }

#define CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(err, cuptifunc)                               \
    if (err != CUPTI_SUCCESS) {                                         \
        const char *errstr;                                             \
        cuptiGetResultString(err, &errstr);                             \
        printf("%s:%d:Error %s for CUPTI API function '%s'\n",          \
                __FILE__, __LINE__, errstr, cuptifunc);                 \
        exit(-1);                                                       \
    }

typedef struct cupti_eventData_st {
    CUpti_EventGroup eventGroup;
    CUpti_EventID eventId;
} cupti_eventData;

// Structure to hold data collected by callback
typedef struct RuntimeApiTrace_st {
    cupti_eventData *eventData;
    uint64_t eventVal;
} RuntimeApiTrace_t;

void CUPTIAPI getEventValueCallback(
                        void *userdata,
                        CUpti_CallbackDomain domain,
                        CUpti_CallbackId cbid,
                        const CUpti_CallbackData *cbInfo) {

    CUptiResult cuptiErr;
    RuntimeApiTrace_t *traceData = (RuntimeApiTrace_t*) userdata;
    size_t bytesRead;

    // This callback is enabled for launch so we shouldn't see anything else.
    if (cbid != CUPTI_RUNTIME_TRACE_CBID_cudaLaunch_v3020) {
        printf("%s:%d: unexpected cbid %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, cbid);
        exit(-1);
    }

    switch(cbInfo->callbackSite) {
        case CUPTI_API_ENTER:
            cudaThreadSynchronize();
            cuptiErr = cuptiSetEventCollectionMode(cbInfo->context, CUPTI_EVENT_COLLECTION_MODE_KERNEL);
            CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiSetEventCollectionMode");
            cuptiErr = cuptiEventGroupEnable(traceData->eventData->eventGroup);
            CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGroupEnable");
            break;

        case CUPTI_API_EXIT:
            bytesRead = sizeof(uint64_t);
            cudaThreadSynchronize();
            cuptiErr = cuptiEventGroupReadEvent(traceData->eventData->eventGroup, CUPTI_EVENT_READ_FLAG_NONE, traceData->eventData->eventId, &bytesRead, &traceData->eventVal);
            CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGroupReadEvent");
            cuptiErr = cuptiEventGroupDisable(traceData->eventData->eventGroup);
            CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGroupDisable");
            break;
    }
}

static void displayEventVal(RuntimeApiTrace_t *trace, char *eventName) {
    printf("Event Name: %s \n", eventName);
    printf("Event Value: %llu\n", (unsigned long long) trace->eventVal);
}

__global__ void kernel(int *arr) {
    __prof_trigger(00);

    int id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    if (id >= N) return;

    __prof_trigger(01);

    if (arr[id] < 4) __prof_trigger(02);
    else             __prof_trigger(03);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int deviceCount;
    CUcontext context = 0;
    CUdevice dev = 0;
    char deviceName[32];
    char *eventName;
    CUptiResult cuptiErr;
    CUpti_SubscriberHandle subscriber;
    cupti_eventData cuptiEvent;
    RuntimeApiTrace_t trace;
    int cap_major, cap_minor;

    CUresult err = cuInit(0);
    CHECK_CU_ERROR(err, "cuInit");

    err = cuDeviceGetCount(&deviceCount);
    CHECK_CU_ERROR(err, "cuDeviceGetCount");

    if (deviceCount == 0) {
        printf("There is no device supporting CUDA.\n");
        return -2;
    }

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: ./a.out <num_threads> <event_name>\n");
        return -2;
    }

    err = cuDeviceGet(&dev, 0);
    CHECK_CU_ERROR(err, "cuDeviceGet");

    err = cuDeviceGetName(deviceName, 32, dev);
    CHECK_CU_ERROR(err, "cuDeviceGetName");

    err = cuDeviceComputeCapability(&cap_major, &cap_minor, dev);
    CHECK_CU_ERROR(err, "cuDeviceComputeCapability");

    printf("CUDA Device Name: %s\n", deviceName);
    printf("CUDA Capability: %d.%d\n", cap_major, cap_minor);

    err = cuCtxCreate(&context, 0, dev);
    CHECK_CU_ERROR(err, "cuCtxCreate");

    cuptiErr = cuptiEventGroupCreate(context, &cuptiEvent.eventGroup, 0);
    CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGroupCreate");

    int threads = atoi(argv[1]);
    eventName = argv[2];

    cuptiErr = cuptiEventGetIdFromName(dev, eventName, &cuptiEvent.eventId);
    if (cuptiErr != CUPTI_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Invalid eventName: %s\n", eventName);
        return -1;
    }

    cuptiErr = cuptiEventGroupAddEvent(cuptiEvent.eventGroup, cuptiEvent.eventId);
    CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGroupAddEvent");

    trace.eventData = &cuptiEvent;

    cuptiErr = cuptiSubscribe(&subscriber, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)getEventValueCallback, &trace);
    CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiSubscribe");

    cuptiErr = cuptiEnableCallback(1, subscriber, CUPTI_CB_DOMAIN_RUNTIME_API, CUPTI_RUNTIME_TRACE_CBID_cudaLaunch_v3020);
    CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEnableCallback");


    int host_arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int *dev_arr;


    cudaMalloc(&dev_arr, sizeof(int) * N);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_arr, &host_arr, sizeof(int) * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    kernel<<< threads, 1 >>>(dev_arr);

    displayEventVal(&trace, eventName);
    trace.eventData = NULL;

    cuptiErr = cuptiEventGroupRemoveEvent(cuptiEvent.eventGroup, cuptiEvent.eventId);
    CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGroupRemoveEvent");

    cuptiErr = cuptiEventGroupDestroy(cuptiEvent.eventGroup);
    CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGroupDestroy");

    cuptiErr = cuptiUnsubscribe(subscriber);
    CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiUnsubscribe");

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

And the SASS code:

```
Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_10
code version = [1,4]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
identifier = cuda.cu

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_10
code version = [1,2]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
identifier = cuda.cu

    code for sm_10
        Function : _Z6kernelPi
    /*0000*/ ;
    /*0008*/     /*0xf0000001e0000004*/     MOV.U16 R0H, g [0x1].U16;
    /*0010*/     /*0x100042050023c780*/     I2I.U32.U16 R1, R0L;
    /*0018*/     /*0xa000000504000780*/     IMAD.U16 R0, g [0x6].U16, R0H, R1;
    /*0020*/     /*0x60014c0100204780*/     ISET.S32.C0 o [0x7f], R0, c [0x1] [0x0], LE;
    /*0028*/     /*0x308001fd6c40c7c8*/     RET C0.EQU;
    /*0030*/ ;
    /*0038*/     /*0x3000000300000500*/     SHL R0, R0, 0x2;
    /*0040*/     /*0xf0000401e0000004*/     IADD R0, g [0x4], R0;
    /*0048*/     /*0x30020001c4100780*/     GLD.U32 R0, global14 [R0];
    /*0050*/     /*0x2000c80104200780*/     ISET.S32.C0 o [0x7f], R0, c [0x1] [0x1], GT;
    /*0058*/     /*0xd00e000180c00780*/     BRA C0.NE, 0x70;
    /*0060*/ ;
    /*0068*/     /*0x308101fd6c4107c8*/     RET;
    /*0070*/ ;
    /*0078*/     /*0x1000e00300000280*/     NOP;
        ............................
```

Comment: Providing command lines to your program is useless if we don't know what the command line options mean. You also don't provide information about what the input data is to your program.  More complete code (host code) would help.

Comment: Sorry, the post ate away the part where i explained the command line usage (forbiden chars). i fixed it now, but i'm invoking the program using **./prof_trigger_test [block_size] [event_name]**. The input array is irrevelant but its an array with 10 elements (N=10)
The host code consists only on creating the array, CUPTI calls to retrieve counter values (based on oficial samples) and kernel call

Comment: Please post both the host code, SASS code (cuobjdump -sass), and the driver version. The compiler has a tendency to move and eliminate __prof_triggers. Older versions of CUPTI only collected the results from 1 SM. The latest version can collect results from all SMs.

Comment: Original post edited, to add host code, and SASS dump as requested.
also forgot to mention, but everything was compiled with no optimization flags or anything else besides the required linker and include paths for CUDA and CUPTI

Answer (score 2):

Collection of prof_trigger_XX varies with architecture. On compute capability 1.* devices the counter value is only collected from 1 SM. On compute capability >= 2 the counter value is collected from all SMs.

The GeForce 9600M GPU is a 1.1 device with 4 SMs.

The example program is launching [block_size] blocks of 1 thread each. This is a little confusing as I think you meant the sample to launch N threads with each block being at most 1 warp. This is not what was implemented in the example code.

```
[block_size]  prof_trigger_00 expected range
1-3           0-1
4-7           1-2
8-11          2-3
```

The expected value is a range as there is no guarantee if the observed SM will be the first SM to receive be dispatched a thread block.